# ID3DXFont::DrawText modifying the IDirect3DDevice9 vtable

Tags: c++, com, direct3d9

I am messing around with Direct3D - modifying vtable entries for a device object so that my functions get called instead the provided ones. I noticed that despite this mostly working, at points something restores the `IDirect3DDevice9` vtable, for example `ID3DXFont::DrawText` - the very first call; ulterior ones don't touch it.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I'm looking for a lighter way to insert my calls, without patching `jmp`s inside the COM methods I want hooked (already works, but somehow being able to do it through the vtables would bring me more joy).

Answer (score 0):

Modifying vtables is pretty much undefined behavior.  Maybe there are caches or different copies of the vtable.  It's all implementation dependent.  You're lucky it works at all!

Comment: Taksi does it, but only for `AddRef` and `Release`. You'd advise I use the plain old `jmp` method? Keep in mind we're talking about COM objects' vtables, which aren't exactly like C++ objects' vtables.